# Strange behavior of full calendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am using Jquery full calender Resource view for scheduling purpose and Is working fine (as expected) but it create some problem in chrome.

[image: recourse view]

you can clearly see that on 18th and 19th the event time are same but it display event in wrong sequence.
Plz... help me to solve out this.

Here is some gson data from my database.

```
{"allDay":"false","color":"","end":"2013-12-18T00:00","resource":10,"start":"2013-12-18T00:00","title":"01:00 to 08:00","__hashCodeCalc":false},
{"allDay":"false","color":"","end":"2013-12-18T00:00","resource":10,"start":"2013-12-18T00:00","title":"09:00 to 21:00","__hashCodeCalc":false},
{"allDay":"false","color":"","end":"2013-12-19T00:00","resource":10,"start":"2013-12-19T00:00","title":"01:00 to 08:00","__hashCodeCalc":false},
{"allDay":"false","color":"","end":"2013-12-19T00:00","resource":10,"start":"2013-12-19T00:00","title":"09:00 to 21:00","__hashCodeCalc":false}
```

I tried to change the sequence of my gson data but it doesn't make any difference.
This code is properly working in Firefox.

Comment: Please add the code/data source you're using and a jsfiddle demonstrating the problem (if possible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that chrome need the start time. When Making the Event, I simply add a second to each Event in the Data and it working fine
example.

```
{"allDay":"false","color":"","end":"2013-12-18T00:00:01-05:00","resource":10,"start":"2013-12-18T00:00:01-05:00","title":"01:00 to 08:00","__hashCodeCalc":false},
{"allDay":"false","color":"","end":"2013-12-18T00:00:01-05:00","resource":10,"start":"2013-12-18T00:00:01-05:00","title":"09:00 to 21:00","__hashCodeCalc":false}
```

Just change the Gson data like this it may help u because it work for me .